# How do you create *yml files?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine2 and I spend a lot of time manually changing (updating) *yml files. With Doctrine1 I used Mysql Workbench with additional plugins to do it but Doctrine2 uses many *yml files - not only one like in previous version. I'd like to know how do you create *yml files? What tool do you use?

Comment: I don't know what Doctrine2 is but I guess those *yml files are just [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) format files.

Comment: I'll try to describe my problem using other words. Assume I have sql dump file from MySQL db. Now I want to change it into *.yml files (YAML files). Every table in separated file. How to do it automatically?

Comment: @jathanism "Tried a text editor?" - What do you mean?

Comment: He's being sarcastic. I think Lucas wants to know how to go from a dump file to yaml files like you could do in Doctrine 1. I'm not sure, but have you looked at the doctrine command line to see if that option is available in Doctrine 2?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering

That section of the docs discusses how to go from your database to yaml, xml, etc. Toward the bottom is the command line of how to do it for yml files. You use the doctrine cli tool or it looks like you can do it through code as well.

Comment: I read and understood whole Doctrine2 manual. I know about it. Although it works better then in Doctrine1 the problem with reverse engineering is it doesn't work entirely correct especially with relations. It isn't recommended way to add changes into *yml files. Do everybody add changes manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your YAML files using the [ORM Designer](http://www.orm-designer.com/) tool.

It uses visual model for the project. You can modify your model and when you export it to YAML, all schema files will be generated automatically, you just need to set the target paths for your modules. You can also import your existing schema files and projects.